# How do you work with "global" configuration within ZF?

Tags: php, zend-framework, configuration, globalization

I'm not really sure what the best way to use global configuration options.
For example, if when a file is uploaded I want to move it in the correct folder.

- I can hardcode the path, but it's **not** really the best thing.
- I can use a CONSTANT
- I can use config.ini and sets some common config options. Maybe then register a config object in Registry

How do you do? Any advice?

Comment: You mean *"it's really not the best thing"*, I assume?

Comment: Indeed :) I edited my question

Answer (score 3):

A [Zend_Config object](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.config.theory_of_operation.html) in the [Registry](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.registry.using.html) is the usual method that ZF follows here.  Many of the ZF classes can accept Configs, and there's pretty much no better way to deal with it within ZF.

(Just remember, the Registry pattern is little more than a glorified global anyway.)

Comment: What do you think to use such with an action helper to be able to do something like $this->getConfiguration()->something ?

Comment: I suppose you could do that, just keep the unit testing implications of that in mind, if you end up unit testing your controllers.

Answer (score 3):

Create a config.ini, and within it separate your configurations like so:

```
[development]
;File Upload settings
FileUpload.path = /some/path

[production]
;File Upload settings
FileUpload.path = /production/path
```

Now somewhere in your Bootstrap.php, you can do this:

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini(
    self::$root . '/config/config.ini',
    'development'
);
self::$registry->configuration = $config;
```

And in any controller:

```
$config = Zend_Registry::get('configuration');
echo $config->FileUpload->path;
```

Answer (score 1):

I use `Zend_Registry::set('foo', '/path/to/correct/folder')` once, and then call it whenever I need it with `Zend_Registry::get('foo')` anytime I need it. Works great!

Comment: I don't think it is wrong (I removed the downvote, I don't downvote anymore). But I do think there are probably better ways of doing it. That said, I know very little...

Comment: The/A Registry is not a global data container. Use `$GLOBALS` for that. ;)

Comment: @KingCrush, $GLOBALS leads to unreadable code, but can you explain what is a registry then?